# How to create link message in "Activity" and in "Chat" which navigates to the Side rail personal tab in MS Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Is it possible to send a notification message to users to navigate to the Personal Tab app in Side rail from the "Activity" or "Chat" window in MS teams?

The notification message in Activity and Chat should have a link that would navigate to the New Personal Tab installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by sending a Deep Link to your app's Personal tab. See more about this at [Create Deep Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links).

To actually *send* the message you have a few options, including:

1. Create a [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams)
2. Use an [incoming Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#setting-up-a-custom-incoming-webhook)
3. Use the [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
4. Use Power Automate (Flow) (there's an app in Teams called the "Flow Bot" which enables you to send messages from Flows directly to a user.

Comment: Is there any way or an api to send deep link wit messages or an adaptive card directly to set of users in teams without bot services. Just an message to specific set of users directly in their chat window but not in teams  or channel.

Comment: Yes, I think that's possible - I don't think you need an actual bot to send a deep link, you just need to make sure you create the link correctly

Comment: Any reference link on how to send messages directly to users would be helpful